# .htacess url rewriting not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to change `http://womenhealthanddiet.com/article_info.php?id=238` to `women-health-article/`. I tried different tutorials and looking for answers on Stack Overflow, but whatever I do to the url it does not change. I am using Godaddy as a webhost. What should I do?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
#Fix Rewrite (-|-) this works as a fix for crazy ass godaddy, 
#thanks david walsh @ (davidwalsh.name)!
Options -Multiviews
RewriteRule ^women-health-article/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ article_info.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This is a little unclear, are you trying to redirect url/women-health-article/ statically to url/article_info.php?id=128 (ie, just the one permanent remap?).

Answer (score 0):

This will statically redirect to article_info.php?id=238

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^(.*)/women-health-article/$  article_info.php?id=238  [R,L]
```

This will dynamically redirect based on an id following the url.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^(.*)/women-health-article/(.*)$  article_info.php?id=$2  [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

for me im always using this code which is work really fine for me

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^women-health-article-([a-zA-Z_0-9-/]+).html$ article_info.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^women-health-article-([a-zA-Z_0-9-/]+).html/$ article_info.php?id=$1
```

using this code inside .htaccess file will give you this result in url

```
http://you-domain-name.com/women-health-article-238.html
```

and if you want to change the url to be more nice you can change your method and make a table inside your database lets say the table name is `article_slug` now this article slug will have article slug just like the id.

now if you make an article you should enter the slug of this article and using it just like you use id

**example**

you have article title (Fitness Train For Women) and the slug is (fitness-women-train)
so the php will be

the URL as .htaccess i write before

```
http://you-domain-name.com/article-fitness-women-train.html

<?php

$getslug = $_GET['slug'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE article_slug = '$getslug' ");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

?>
```

and the .htaccess file for this example will be

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^article-([a-zA-Z_0-9-/]+).html$ article_info.php?slug=$1
    RewriteRule ^article-([a-zA-Z_0-9-/]+).html/$ article_info.php?slug=$1
```

so that's it